# How to add control layers in leaflet from a local geojson file

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Using the framework from the example at http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html I substituted the line:

```
var cities = new L.LayerGroup();

L.marker([39.61, -105.02]).bindPopup('This is Littleton, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.74, -104.99]).bindPopup('This is Denver, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.73, -104.8]).bindPopup('This is Aurora, CO.').addTo(cities),
L.marker([39.77, -105.23]).bindPopup('This is Golden, CO.').addTo(cities);
```

for:

```
var cities = new L.LayerGroup();

$.getJSON("cvs.geojson",function(data){
    var cvsIcon = L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'CVS.svg',
        iconSize: [45, 45]
    });
    L.geoJson(data, {
        pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
            var marker = L.marker(latlng, {icon: cvsIcon});
            marker.bindPopup(feature.properties.Address);
            return marker;
        }
    }).addTo(cities);
});
```

The rest of the code is the same as the example so im fairly certain it is how I am loading the data in, or how the geojson is being passed to the "cities" variable.  Both the cvs.geojson and CVS.svg files are in the same folder as the index.html file.  I'm fairly new to javascript and leaflet, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you *really* sure the file is being loaded?

Comment: Make sure you can use your `CVS.svg` icon that easily. From what I remember, it was not that straight forward to use SVG icon. But things may have changed. E.g., you could start by using standard icon and see if it works. Finally, you do not describe exactly what is your problem?

Comment: try this http://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson.html

Comment: Try to work in small steps: First display your geojson with regular markers, then add the custom icon, or the other way around. Learning (the network tab in your) browsers' developer tools will help debugging these kinds of problems.

Comment: I ended up solving the issue by using omnivore to load in the geojson, thanks for the tips